# Read-only access for Heroku Postgres Databases

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku, readonly

I have a Heroku Postgres database for my application. I can easily access the `psql` shell using the provided `DATABASE_URL` from Heroku

```
psql $(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a my_app)
psql (9.6.1)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDSE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

d5i032ahpfiv07=>
```

And by default, this user seems to have full access to update and drop tables

```
d5i032ahpfiv07=> SELECT 
  table_name, 
  string_agg(privilege_type, ', ') as privileges
FROM information_schema.role_table_grants 
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
  AND grantee = current_user
GROUP BY 1
;

            table_name             |                          privileges
-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 articles                          | INSERT, TRIGGER, REFERENCES, TRUNCATE, DELETE, UPDATE, SELECT
 comment_flags                     | TRIGGER, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE, REFERENCES
 comment_likes                     | TRUNCATE, REFERENCES, TRIGGER, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE
 comments                          | INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE, REFERENCES, TRIGGER
 communities                       | TRIGGER, REFERENCES, TRUNCATE, DELETE, UPDATE, SELECT, INSERT
 .....
```

I'd love to set up "Read Only" users in the database so that people can view this data without fear of running "DROP TABLE" or some other destructive command.

How can I go about setting up a read-only user on Heroku Postgres?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a [Heroku Postgres Follower Database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-follower-databases)

> A database follower is a read-only copy of the leader database that
>   stays up-to-date with the leader database data. As writes and other
>   data modifications are committed in the leader database, the changes
>   are streamed, in real-time, to the follower databases.

Then simply run your analytics, dataclips, and other read-only applications against the follower. This is a very standard configuration that safeguards your main DB, and has added performance benefits: you can hammer it with queries (which are often intensive and have different cache profiles) without affecting your user-facing application.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice solution. Small follow-up: if someone accidentally runs some destructive command on the follower, I'll have to rebuild it's data right? How can I be alerted (or check manually) if that happens? I'm sure there's some way to compare the state of the follower to the leader?

Comment: I'm guessing it isn't possible for a destructive command to be run on the follower since it's read-only, but I was also wondering the same thing just now....

Comment: Under the hood, a Heroku follower uses a Postgres hot standby. Hot standbys will not allow any queries that modify the data, so the same applies to Heroku followers.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hot-standby.html

Answer (score 9):

Adam's suggestion to create a follower database is usually the right solution for this, but it's possible to create a read-only role (or any other permissions you want), for any Heroku Postgres database, even one that isn't a follower.

Heroku has detailed documentation for this at [Heroku Postgres Credentials](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql-credentials), but briefly:

**Create Heroku credential**

```bash
heroku pg:credentials:create <addon_name> --name new_credential -a <app_name>
```

`<addon_name>` is the name of your Postgres addon, which you can find by running `heroku pg:info -a <app_name>` and checking the "Add-on" line in the output.

The new credential is named `new_credential` in the above command, but you can use whatever name you want.

**Set permissions**

Creating the `new_credential` credential also creates a `new_credential` *role* ([see Postgres roles documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/user-manag.html)) in your Postgres database. You can set the permissions for `new_credential` like any other role, using psql. By default, the role has no permissions. The Heroku docs give this example, to run in psql:

```sql
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA PUBLIC TO new_credential;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO new_credential;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public
  GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO new_credential;
```

The above sets the `new_credential` role to have read-only privileges. See the [Postgres documentation on privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html) for more details.

**Attach the credential**

Before you can use the credential, you need to attach it to your app:

```bash
heroku addons:attach <addon_name> --credential new_credential -a <app_name>
```

When you run the `addons:attach` command, the output will include a new config var named `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_<COLOUR>_URL`, where `<COLOUR>` is some colour. This config var holds a Postgres connection URL you can use to connect to the database using the `new_credential` role.

**Using the credential**

In an app, connect to the database using the new config var created in the last step instead of the default `DATABASE_URL` (which still contains the default, read-write credentials).

You can also use the new role in psql:

```bash
heroku pg:psql <addon_name> --credential new_credential -a <app_name>
```

Or, if you want to use psql directly as in your example, you can use the new colour URL:

```bash
psql $(heroku config:get HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_<COLOUR>_URL -a <app_name>)
```

When you connect to Postgres using the new role, any attempts to create, update, or drop data will be rejected by Postgres due to the role's permissions.

Answer (score 2):

It has kind of already been said, but this is a simple solution for those who don't want to get real technical.

https://data.heroku.com/dataclips

You can just create dataclips here for each or any individual Heroku app that you have. You run whatever queries you like, and then you can share it via **URL, CSV, JSON, Google Sheet,** or you can even add individual people or teams to have access to them.

It's nice cause you have the Heroku web UI to use (rather than through CLI), and it doesn't necessarily give someone complete access to the DB, just what you want them to see; which is suitable for some people's specific needs/scenarios.